# Declare and access struct from a C library in C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm using a C library which has a struct called dataSet which is used throughout the library. I can declare the struct in my C++ code and pass it to the methods in the C library and it works fine, but I don't know how to access items from this struct in C++ as I get read file access violation. I'm not sure if I should be using the extern command somehow.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cgp.h"
int main() {
    struct dataSet* trainingData = NULL;
    trainingData = initialiseDataSetFromFile("sinwaves.csv"); // Returns dataSet* filled with values
    double** x = getInputFromDataSet(trainingData); 
    std::cout << x[1] << std::endl; // <--- ERROR: read file access violation.
}
```

cgp.h:

```
struct dataSet;
double** getInputFromDataSet(struct dataSet*);
```

cgp.c:

```
#include "cgp.h"
struct dataSet {
    int numSamples;
    int numInputs;
    int numOutputs;
    double **inputData;
    double **outputData;
};
double** getInputFromDataSet(struct dataSet* ds) {
    return (ds->numInputs);
}
```

Preferably I want to be able to simply do trainingData->numInputs in my main.cpp file, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Full Error (on the line commented in main.cpp):
Exception thrown: read access violation.
x was 0x1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What leads you to believe that this is impossible? Have you actually tried it? What happened?

Comment: You just need to put the struct declaration in the header - exactly the same as if you only had C code.

Comment: Yes, I get "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed" error. I found an answer on stack overflow which said you should make a function like my getInputFromDataSet function, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: [Edit] your post to quote the full error, including the file/line number it implicates. And this goes for _any_ errors, since the one you alluded to in your post is different from that in your comment.

Comment: The way you're currently accessing the struct member is fine.  The error you're getting suggests what you're getting back from the function is bad.  You should validate that it gets populated properly.

Comment: That `getInputFromDataSet` function's return value doesn't make sense.  Where is there a `numInputs` in the `dataSet` struct?

Comment: Your declaration lacks `numInputs`, yet somehow you are able to use it. Please post the actual code you are running.

Comment: I added the full error at the end.

Comment: If that code compiled, then that is a different `dataSet` than the one you are showing us.

Comment: I have voted to close as the given code is incomplete and inconsistent. We need a minimal, complete example that quotes all errors and shows how you assign all values that might be to blame. Instead, we currently have an incomplete struct declaration and no idea what `initialiseDataSetFromFile()` does to said struct or what `getInputFromDataSet()` is meant to return. In preparing a minimal sample that others can actually compile/run, you might well answer your own question and solve your own problem.

Comment: Sorry, this was a stupid typo, getInputFromDataSet should be ds->inputData. Thank you @underscore_d. But since I've asked this question already is it possible to make it so I can access trainingData->inputData from my C++ file, without having to use getInputFromDataSet?

Comment: You could make the full declaration of the struct public in the header, instead of making it an opaque type whose implementation is know only to the C source file.

Comment: "Read access violation" means that your code has a bug somewhere. There is no issue with accessing C structures for C++, per se, if it is done correctly. Unfortunately, nobody will be able to help you figure out the bug until you show something that meets all requirements of a [mre], as explained in the [help]. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to simply do trainingData->numInputs in my main.cpp file, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

The library has been designed in such a way, as to hide the definition of `dataSet`, and thereby prevent access to `numInputs` and other members.

Technically, you can access the member, simply by defining the same class as is defined in cgp.c. The definition must match **exactly**. Otherwise the program will violate One Definition Rule, and be ill-formed (no diagnostic required). As such, this can easily break if the library is later modified. I recommend to avoid this.